# Java Generic Enum as a Parameter

Tags: java, generics, enums

So I have several Enums defined like the following. I have a method that uses the Enum to find the value.

```
public enum MyEnum1
{
   STRING1("My String1"),
   STRING2("My String2"),
   STRING3("My String3"),
   STRINGLESS("String not found");

   private String s;

   private MyEnum1(String s) { this.s = s; }

   public String getValue() { return s; }
}

public enum MyEnum2
{
   STRING1("My String1"),
   STRING2("My String2"),
   STRING3("My String3"),
   STRINGLESS("String not found");

   private String s;

   private MyEnum2(String s) { this.s = s; }

   public String getValue() { return s; }
}

public class MyClass1
{
    public static String getPlacement(String myString)
    {
        for (MyEnum1 a: MyEnum1.values())
            if (myString.contains(a.toString()))
                return a.getValue();

        return MyEnum1.STRINGLESS.getValue();
     }
}

public class MyClass2
{
    public static String getPlacement(String myString)
    {
        for (MyEnum2 a: MyEnum2.values())
            if (myString.contains(a.toString()))
                return a.getValue();

        return MyEnum2.STRINGLESS.getValue();
     }
}
```

Right now I have 5 Enums defined that all get processed by the same getPlacement method but I had to create 5 different MyClass classes (MyClass2, MyClass3...) with MyEnum2, MyEnum3... hard coded in the For Loop to make it happen.

I've tried...

```
public static String getPlacement(Enum e, String myString) {}
```

and

```
public static String getPlacement(Enum<?> e, String myString) {}
```

but neither works.

I would like to pass an Enum to the getPlacement method as a parameter thus allowing me to only have one MyClass class that could process the 5 different Enums.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To preserve the exact semantics of your `getPlacement`, you can do it like this:

```
interface StringValue {
    String getValue();
}

enum MyEnum1 implements StringValue {
    ...
    private String stringValue;
    ...

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return stringValue;
    }
}

static <E extends Enum<E> & StringValue>
String getPlacement(Class<E> enumClass, String inValue) {
    for(E constant : enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
        if(inValue.contains(constant.toString()))
            return constant.getValue();
    }
    return Enum.valueOf(enumClass, "STRINGLESS").getValue();
}
```

I am not sure if the exact semantics here are actually important to you. If they're not, there are simpler ways. If you don't need `contains` you can just use [`Enum#valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-). If you can override `toString` (because you can also use [`Enum#name`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name--)) then you don't need an interface.

And also, like all complicated situations with enum, things may be much simpler for you if you just do not use enum. A `final` class with a private constructor and `public static final` constants can do many things that enum can not (like inherit from an abstract supertype...).

Comment: Thanks for the help this doesn't exactly what I wanted!  I'm looking for Key,Value pairs and I need have control of the order in which the keys are checked which is why I chose Enum.

I'm placing users in an LDAP tree and you can be any combination of a Board member, Faculty, Staff, Consultant, Alumni, ...., and/or a Student. I need to determine your container(which controls your rights) by the hierarchy of your user type in the order I just listed. If you are a Board member and student you should be placed in the Board container. Faculty and Staff = Staff and so on.

Thanks again!!!

Comment: That should say it DOES exactly what I wanted!  Much thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Add such interface to your code.

```
public interface Named {
    String name();
}
```

Let all of your enums implement it like

```
public enum MyEnum1 implements Named {...}
```

Then declare your method with interface like:

```
public static String getPlacement(Named enumValue, String myString) {}
```

Inside of the `getPlacement()` method call `enumValue.name()` instead of `toString()`, although you can do the exact same with toString(), depends what you gonna use in your interface definition (which can be named as you like, not necessarily `Named`).

By the way, using single letters as variable names is usually considered a bad practice.

Comment: This worked with the exception that I could not loop through the Enum values using valueOf().  It's as if it didn't inherit the Iteration abilities of the Enum.

Oh and I only use single letter variables as iterators and counters. I just got lazy and instead of creating MyVar1 or something I just used s. :-D

Answer (score 0):

The Enum base class [java.lang.Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) has a static factory method `valueOf(Class, String)` for constructing an arbitrary enum instance. With a bit of generics magic you should be able to solve your problem.

```
public enum MyEnum1 {
   STRING1("MyEnum1 String1"),
   STRING2("MyEnum1 String2"),
   STRING3("MyEnum1 String3"),
   STRINGLESS("MyEnum1 String not found");

   private String s;
   private MyEnum1(String s) { this.s = s; }

   @Override
   public String toString() { return s; }
}

public enum MyEnum2 {
   STRING1("MyEnum2 String1"),
   STRING2("MyEnum2 String2"),
   STRING3("MyEnum2 String3"),
   STRINGLESS("MyEnum2 String not found");

   private String s;
   private MyEnum2(String s) { this.s = s; }

   @Override
   public String toString() { return s; }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getPlacement(MyEnum1.class, "STRING1").name());
    System.out.println(getPlacement(MyEnum2.class, "STRING3").name());
    System.out.println(getPlacement(MyEnum2.class, "foobar").name());
}

public static <T extends Enum<T>> Enum<T> getPlacement(Class<T> clazz, String value) {
    try {
        return Enum.valueOf(clazz, value);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return Enum.valueOf(clazz, "STRINGLESS");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Looks like your `getPlacement` should return `T`.

Comment: Since the definition of Enum is recursive, Enum<T> should result in the same output. I find the addition to be a hair more readable; but you're correct that the verbosity is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help but getPlacement is returning the same string value that I pass to it instead of MyEnum# String#